# Get fields of requested entry in module

Tags: craft3, modules

Instead of writing a lot of logic in twig in my template, I tried to create a service and get the fields related to the requested entry in a module. I then want to create a new twig variable to output the whole block in my template. After a lot try and error and reading the docs I'm still not able to achieve this. Maybe someone can give me a hint where to start.

So the question is: How can I get the fields related to the requested entry in a module?

Comment: The question is "where and when?". You want Craft to route the request and just inject some additional globals into the request? Then you could use the after action event and add a global. You could as well create a twig function for it, so you call it only when you need it and not every time.